# Mongoid, Child Models are not creating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I have two models `Owner` and `Shop`:

```
class Owner
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  # Fields
  field :name, type: String

 # Associations
  has_many :shops, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shops


  # Validations
  validates_presence_of :name

end

class Shop
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

   # Fields
  field :name, type: String
  field :address, type: String

  belongs_to :owner

  # Validations
  validates_presence_of :name, :address, :owner

end
```

Now I try to create owner

```
2.times do
  owner = Owner.create(name: Faker::Name.name)
  owner.save

   3.times do
    shop = Shop.create
    shop.name = Faker::Company.name
    shop.owner = owner
    shop.address = "#{Faker::Address.street_address} #{Faker::Address.building_number}"
    shop.save
   end
   owner.save
end
```

When I start this. It creates Owners but does not create its Shops. I dont know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not creating due to validations, try `Shop.new` instead of `Shop.create`

```
2.times do
  owner = Owner.new(name: Faker::Name.name)
  if owner.save!

    3.times do
      shop = Shop.new
      shop.name = Faker::Company.name
      shop.owner = owner
      shop.address = "#{Faker::Address.street_address} #{Faker::Address.building_number}"
      shop.save!
    end
  end       
end
```

Comment: what error is it giving? try using `save!` instead of `save`, it will trigger errors